# asp gridview plus button command

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview based on a Acces DB in .aspx

I added +1 column to the grid, which is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="view">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" CausesValidation="False" id="Button1"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have a button outside of the grid: *Button2*

Could I add a command to *Button1*, to simulate to click on *Button2* as well?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Found a link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycbsc785(v=vs.85).aspx): that talks specifically about wiring multiple events to the same handler, from MSDN:

> If you already have an event handler, you can bind several control
>   events to it. These multiple events can be from the same control or
>   one event from several different controls, as long as the events all
>   have the same method signature. For example, you might want to bind
>   the Click events of several Button server controls on an ASP.NET page
>   to a single event handler. When your handler is called, you can
>   determine which control caused the event.

Yes! If you are familiar with wiring up a button then all you have to do is point both of them to the same function and clicking either one will fire the same function.

If you want to do this withing visual studio just double click each button in the designer and this will give you a function on the code behind, within that function just add a call to the function you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a seperate function that is called from both buttons. 
Like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonCallFunc();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonCallFunc();
}
protected void buttonCallFunc()
{
    //Code goes here
}
```